# I am failing to get data from cloud firestore while using flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

At first, when i started writing my calls to get data from firestore, it worked. But when i tried writing more docs to my collection, it failed to bring data for the docs i recently added. Then, when i deleted the first one i added, i stopped receiveing data from firestore all together. I have tried several methods, but have all ended in failure.

````
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class collect extends StatefulWidget {

    @override
    _collectState createState() => _collectState();
    }

    class _collectState extends State<collect>
    {
    Future _data;
 
    void initState()
    {
    super.initState();
   
    _data = getStuff();
    }

    Future getStuff()
    async {
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("buses").get();
    return qn.docs;
    }


    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   

    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _data,
        builder: (_, snapshot)
        {
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          {
            return Center(
              child:Text("Loading")
            );
          }
          else if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
            {
              return ListView.builder(itemCount: snapshot.data.length,itemBuilder:(_, index)
              {
                return Container(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data()["name"].toString()),
                    subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].data()["price"].toString()),
                  ),
                );
              });
            }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7FqF.jpg)
````

Comment: Could you please tell me the output of `print(_data);` ?

Comment: Instance of 'Future<dynamic >'

Answer (score 1):

Define your database call as,

```
Future getStuff() async {
  var docs;
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("buses")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) {
    docs = querySnapshot.docs;
  });
  return docs;
}
```

Then use the `FutureBuilder` in the `build()` function as,

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
          future: getStuff(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                    return Container(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                            snapshot.data[index].data()["name"].toString()),
                        subtitle: Text(
                            snapshot.data[index].data()["price"].toString()),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I wrapped the `FutureBuilder` inside a `Center` just for clarity, you may remove that `Center` widget.

Comment: This didn't work only getting 1 result instead of all 3

Comment: Maybe i should give you my email so that we communicate better and i give you screenshots of my situation

Comment: @JehúMtine do you mean you are getting data from only one document? I assume then it has to be something wrong with your database structure since I have tested my code with one of my databases and it returned data from all the documents in it just fine.